# wpf data binding detail with one to one association (entity framework)

Tags: .net, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, datasource

I have a class Patient where each patient can have zero or one address and each address has one patient. I followed this [Walkthroug](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465159.aspx) where they use the entity framework and code first. Dragging the Patient data source on a WPF window creates a grid with a Patient CollectionViewSource just like in the tutorial with the Department. My problem is now that I can't add the Address data source to the window like they do with the Courses property in the tutorial (they have a one to many relationship there). The Address property from Patient is sort of grayed out:

[image]

I tried adding an Address property via path within Xaml:

```
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource patientViewSource}">
...
  <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="patientDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="lastNameColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}" />                
      <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="addressStreetColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Address.Street}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
...
</Grid>
```

The result was that the street from existing patients was shown as intended. But as soon as i try to insert a new patient and address by writing a patient name and a street name into a blank grid row i get an InvalidOperationException, stating "Two-way binding requires Path or XPath". I guess the reason why i cannot just drag the Address data source onto the window is, that we don't deal with a standard 1:n relationship here.

Can somebody tell me please how to make it possible that the program automatically creates (and persists) a new Address instance which is connected to the right patient, as soon as I enter a street name?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. One has to expand Address and then click on Details:

[image]

After this it is draggable.

It would have been easier if this was the default selection...